# Postgres - use a dictionary to convert column names?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table with columns FIRSTNAME LASTNAME and I want to create a third column that combines those two columns into FIRSTNAME_LASTNAME but ALSO uses a special dictionary to convert some of the names. Say I just want to apply it to the FIRSTNAME, e.g.:

```
Albert -> Funnyguy, Kathleen -> Nerd, Megan -> Weirdo
```

So the new column for the "Albert Jones" row would be "Funnyguy_Jones".

Currently I do this in psycopg2 by reading in all the rows (in batches because the db is huge), using a python dictionary to convert and create the new column, then sending out the updates with `UPDATE table SET newcol = tmp.newcol FROM (VALUES ...)` etc. This is very slow because of reading it into python. Any tips?

EDIT: not all of the names have conversions (only like 10% of them do, for those I want to keep the original name)

Comment: the special dictionary is also a table?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I could set it up as one if that's easier. Say, FIRSTNAME NEWNAME as the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `left join` has a match `COALESCE` will choose `t2.newName`, other wise you will choose `t1.firstName`

```
SELECT t1.firstName,
       t1.lastName,
       COALESCE(t2.newName, t1.firstName) + '_' + t1.lastName as combinedName
FROM firstTable t1
LEFT JOIN newTable t2
       ON t1.firstName = t2.firstName
```